# Error : The support for this usage was removed in Celery 5.0. Instead you should use `--app` as a global option

Tags: docker-compose, celery, fastapi, celery-task, flower

I am having a fastapi when i build container image i was unable to run the celery worker

`dockercompose` file

```py
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8000"
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - redis

  worker:
    build: .
    command: celery worker --app=worker.celery --loglevel=info

    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:6-alpine

  dashboard:
    build: .
    command: flower --app=worker.celery --port=5555 --broker=redis://redis:6379/0
    ports:
      - 5556:5555
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis
      - worker
```

I am getting this error `You are using` --app `as an option of the worker sub-command`

`celery worker --app celeryapp <...>`
The support for this usage was removed in Celery 5.0. Instead you should use `--app` as a global option:
`celery --app celeryapp worker <...>`
`Error: no such option: --app`. I am not sure where i am doing wrong

Comment: It's telling you to move the `--app` parameter one step to the left, so that it's a parameter to `celery` instead of to `celery worker`?

Comment: The error message shows you what you need to change: `celery worker --app celeryapp` should be `celery --app celeryapp worker`

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you what you need to change - the `--app` parameter has moved from being a parameter to `celery worker` to being a parameter to `celery` instead.

Your old command:

```
celery worker --app=worker.celery --loglevel=info
```

needs to be changed by moving `--app` to the left (so that it is a parameter to `celery` instead):

```
celery --app=worker.celery worker --loglevel=info
```